# Load files from folder

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm loading a folder with files using this method:

```
NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GBC/Caras/"];
    fotosJugadores = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: @"/Users/exular/Developer/GBC/exular/GBC/Caras/" error: &error];
```

But the problem remains to get the same functionality to do it once the app will run in the device, how can I set a folder with all that images to be available in the device? Is there any bundle method similar to contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: to load images from project bundle, something like imageNamed: ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any bundle method...

When you start a question like that, the answer is usually found in the [`NSBundle` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  In this case, the answer is yes, there is such a method.  You will see that if you read the documentation.  You should **always** check the documentation before asking for help.

Comment: - (id)initWithPath:(NSString *)fullPath. Sorry